# Filter object props based on the specified array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object with the following structure

```
{ cardControlItem: 'Tidak',
  cardDirectUseItem: 'Tidak',
  kbUnspscUuid: '6a564b8e-2976-4fde-8759-7951970d7500',
  substoreUuid: '2f2b04bb-8b80-4b1f-b827-bf20311e31ee',
  cardDetailMin: 654,
  cardDetailMax: 65,
  cardDetailIncrement: 754,
  cardDetailPriceOverall: 4534,
  cardDetailPriceUnit: 0,
  ltMeasurementMinUuid: 'fddca37a-d0a3-40a4-8537-e84375b01601',
  ltMeasurementMaxUuid: '2bc6d7d2-5167-4459-9910-a65839008afd' }
```

and I have a list of keys in an array

```
['cardControlItem', 'cardDirectUseItem', 'kbUnspscUuid', 'substoreUuid', 'stockCardGroupUuid', 'stockCardBatchUuid']
```

How do I reduce it according to the array specified

expected output:

```
{ cardControlItem: 'Tidak',
  cardDirectUseItem: 'Tidak',
  kbUnspscUuid: '6a564b8e-2976-4fde-8759-7951970d7500',
  substoreUuid: '2f2b04bb-8b80-4b1f-b827-bf20311e31ee' }
```

P.S: I spent 3 hours spent to find similar problems on StackOverflow. What is the right title for this kind of problems :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution. I am filter the properties which are in the `obj` (`filter` part) and then iterate over the properties which exist (`reduce` part) and assign values of the properties into new object (`acc`).

```js
const obj = { 
   cardControlItem: 'Tidak',
   cardDirectUseItem: 'Tidak',
   kbUnspscUuid: '6a564b8e-2976-4fde-8759-7951970d7500',
   substoreUuid: '2f2b04bb-8b80-4b1f-b827-bf20311e31ee',
   cardDetailMin: 654,
   cardDetailMax: 65,
   cardDetailIncrement: 754,
   cardDetailPriceOverall: 4534,
   cardDetailPriceUnit: 0,
   ltMeasurementMinUuid: 'fddca37a-d0a3-40a4-8537-e84375b01601',
   ltMeasurementMaxUuid: '2bc6d7d2-5167-4459-9910-a65839008afd' 
};

const keys = ['cardControlItem', 'cardDirectUseItem', 'kbUnspscUuid', 'substoreUuid', 'stockCardGroupUuid', 'stockCardBatchUuid'];

const mapped = keys.filter(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                   .reduce((acc, key) => { acc[key] = obj[key]; return acc }, {});

console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Explaining your solution might be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

```
 const filter = (obj, arr) => Object.assign(...arr.map(el => ({[el]: obj[el]})));
```

so one can do

```
const result = filter({a:1, b:2, c:3}, ["a", "b"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

.Loop throught the array and check if the object has this key, if it is so then create a new object with this keys instead of mutating the original one

```js
var orgObject = {
  cardControlItem: 'Tidak',
  cardDirectUseItem: 'Tidak',
  kbUnspscUuid: '6a564b8e-2976-4fde-8759-7951970d7500',
  substoreUuid: '2f2b04bb-8b80-4b1f-b827-bf20311e31ee',
  cardDetailMin: 654,
  cardDetailMax: 65,
  cardDetailIncrement: 754,
  cardDetailPriceOverall: 4534,
  cardDetailPriceUnit: 0,
  ltMeasurementMinUuid: 'fddca37a-d0a3-40a4-8537-e84375b01601',
  ltMeasurementMaxUuid: '2bc6d7d2-5167-4459-9910-a65839008afd'
}


var keys = ['cardControlItem', 'cardDirectUseItem', 'kbUnspscUuid', 'substoreUuid', 'stockCardGroupUuid', 'stockCardBatchUuid']

var newObj = {};
keys.forEach(function(item) {
  if (orgObject.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
    newObj[item] = orgObject[item]

  }

})

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = { cardControlItem: 'Tidak',
  cardDirectUseItem: 'Tidak',
  kbUnspscUuid: '6a564b8e-2976-4fde-8759-7951970d7500',
  substoreUuid: '2f2b04bb-8b80-4b1f-b827-bf20311e31ee',
  cardDetailMin: 654,
  cardDetailMax: 65,
  cardDetailIncrement: 754,
  cardDetailPriceOverall: 4534,
  cardDetailPriceUnit: 0,
  ltMeasurementMinUuid: 'fddca37a-d0a3-40a4-8537-e84375b01601',
  ltMeasurementMaxUuid: '2bc6d7d2-5167-4459-9910-a65839008afd' };
  
 var keys = ['cardControlItem', 'cardDirectUseItem', 'kbUnspscUuid', 'substoreUuid', 'stockCardGroupUuid', 'stockCardBatchUuid'];
 
 var new_data = {};
 for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  if(data.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])){
    new_data[keys[i]] = data[keys[i]];
  }
 }
 
 console.log(new_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```js
let obj = { cardControlItem: 'Tidak',
  cardDirectUseItem: 'Tidak',
  kbUnspscUuid: '6a564b8e-2976-4fde-8759-7951970d7500',
  substoreUuid: '2f2b04bb-8b80-4b1f-b827-bf20311e31ee',
  cardDetailMin: 654,
  cardDetailMax: 65,
  cardDetailIncrement: 754,
  cardDetailPriceOverall: 4534,
  cardDetailPriceUnit: 0,
  ltMeasurementMinUuid: 'fddca37a-d0a3-40a4-8537-e84375b01601',
  ltMeasurementMaxUuid: '2bc6d7d2-5167-4459-9910-a65839008afd' }
  
let  comparator = ['cardControlItem', 'cardDirectUseItem', 'kbUnspscUuid', 'substoreUuid', 'stockCardGroupUuid', 'stockCardBatchUuid'];
  
  
 Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{
  if(!comparator.includes(key)){
    delete obj[key]
  }
 })
 
 console.log(obj)
```

output
{ cardControlItem: 'Tidak',
  cardDirectUseItem: 'Tidak',
  kbUnspscUuid: '6a564b8e-2976-4fde-8759-7951970d7500',
  substoreUuid: '2f2b04bb-8b80-4b1f-b827-bf20311e31ee
}